# best way to modify &understand habitrpg (or any kind of github project)?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, github, bower

I want to modify habitrpg, add & delete some features like instead of strength i'll add ===> developer skills or instead of pets i'll add real properties of mine etc.

So, as far as i understand, i need just nodejs,npm packages and the "website" folder of habitrpg project.

What will be the best way to split, remove some files and modify the bone structure of habitrpg?

PS : Sorry, that's probably a dumb question but i couldn't find a proper way to start, troubling for days. I'm not a developer, just trying to learn as a hobysist. I know frontend, js/jquery/c++ but a backend developer. I know nodejs but not in advanced way.